# CakePHP pagination, how do I sort by the count of a contained model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Using CakePHP 2.3, I'm retrieving data using a paginator. So, say my models are Countries having many Cities, and in my CountryController I have...

```
$this->Paginator->settings = [
    'fields' => [
         'id'
         'country_name'
     ],
     'contain' => [
         'City' => [
             'id'
             'city_name',
             'conditions' => [
                 'population >' => 1000000;
             ]
         ]
     ]
];
```

...which gets me a list of all counties with each row containing a list of any populous cities.

In the view I am obviously able to iterate `foreach ($cities as $city)` and echo `$country['country_name']` etc. and also if I wish I can show a count of the contained cities by echoing `count($country['City'])`.

Using the paginator I can sort the country results by passing back a field name in the query string, e.g. `sort=country_name`, but how can I get the results to sort by the count of the contained cities?

Comment: Check this link it can be the helper key for your problem.
[Count in contain Cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877486/count-in-contain-cakephp-3)

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately not possible to sort by the count of the hasMany Table using the custom Cakephp Pagination. Your best bet is to use `counterCache` as described in the [Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count).

You will need to have a field in country table, named as `city_count`. This field will be updated in the Country Table automatically by Cakephp whenever there is a save operation on `city` table.

Since you only want to count the cities with population > 100K. You can specify the condition in `counterScope` which will only update the column when condition is met.

This can be defined in your City Model as below:

```
class City extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'counterCache' => true,
            'counterScope' => array(
              'City.population > ' => 1000000
            )            
        )
    );
}
```